# Spring boot 2 rest api custome annotation for validation check not triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-rest

I am creating a rest api for upload image. For validate multipart object i am creating annotation. But its not triggered. also putting debugging point and check. Below is my annotaion code

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Payload;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ValidImage.Validators.class})
public @interface ValidImage {
    String message() default "Invalid image file";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    class Validators implements ConstraintValidator<ValidImage, MultipartFile> {

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(MultipartFile multipartFile, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            System.out.println("Validation Called");
            boolean result = true;

            String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
            if (!isSupportedContentType(contentType)) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
                        "Only PNG or JPG images are allowed.")
                       .addConstraintViolation();

                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private boolean isSupportedContentType(String contentType) {
            return contentType.equals("image/png")
                    || contentType.equals("image/jpg")
                    || contentType.equals("image/jpeg");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my controller mapping

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RestController
@Validated
public class ImageStorageController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageStorageController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ImageStorageService imageStorageService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/images", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadImage(@ValidImage @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile imageFile) throws IOException {
        Long imageId = imageStorageService.save(imageFile);

        String imageUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/images/")
                .path(String.valueOf(imageId)).toUriString();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new UploadImageResponse(imageFile.getOriginalFilename(), imageUri, imageFile.getContentType(),
                imageFile.getSize()));
    }
}
```

And i am handle this validation in global exception handler like this

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        final ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        apiError.setMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        apiError.addValidationErrors(ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
    }
```

i found couple of solution but its not working for my case. Any solution help will appreciate.

Comment: Try to add @Valid annotation to imageFile  argument

Comment: @Alexander.Furer so i have to user `@Valid` with `@ValidImage`

Comment: Have you tried it? Works?

Comment: @Alexander.Furer added but it gives error like `The annotation @ValidImage must define the attribute payload`

Comment: @Alexander.Furer added `@Valid` but not working

Comment: Now it's invoked at least. Just add payload attribute, follow the "developing  custom validators" guide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215923/discussion-between-chirag-and-alexander-furer).

Comment: The error you get is runtime or compile?

Comment: I think retention of your customer annotation should be compile as well. Please check the samples

Comment: can you give me some hint or sample code for that

Comment: have check that retention policy is their a `RUNTIME`

Comment: Are you sure payload is array?

Comment: `Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};`

Comment: does custome annonation works with bean only not work with `@RequestParam`